# UserManager's AutoSaveChanges in .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I would like to disable automatic SaveChanges method calls of UserManager. I've found that it is possible to do it by setting AutoSaveChanges property of UserStore. But what is the best practice for such things in .NET Core 2.1? Is it possible to do in Startup.cs by configuring IdentityBuilder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a class that inherits form `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore<IdentityUser>` and set `AutoSaveChanges` to `false` in the constructor and then register this class to `IServiceCollection` before `AddEntityFrameworkStores`.

```
public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<IdentityUser>
{
    public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        AutoSaveChanges = false;
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IUserStore<IdentityUser>, CustomUserStore>();

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
}
```

Comment: And then the default UserManager will pick it up and use it?

Comment: yes, `UserManager` have a dependency on `IUserStore<T>` which is registered by `services.AddScoped<IUserStore<IdentityUser>, CustomUserStore>()`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test at the moment, but it sounds very promising! I'll take it

Comment: Still works in .NET 5.   Reference newer issue for more details on implementation.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69843463/net-5-set-autosavechanges-to-false-in-startup/69903204#69903204