# Using only one SaveChanges call doesn't seem to update my database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm doing several things in my method; they're necessary as far as I concerned, but optimizing the code isn't what this question is for.

In this method I'm creating a user, adding the user to a role, creating a Directorate and creating a record in a `DirectorateUsers` table to link the user to the new Directorate.

There's a few database operations here, so I wanted to try and reduce load on the database by only calling SaveChanges once.

It doesn't seem to be doing anything though; I'm not seeing a new directorate being added and the directorateuser isn't being added either. It creates the user and adds it to the specified role, however.

Is it possible to batch multiple changes to data in Entity Framework this way or do I have to `await db.SaveChangesAsync()` every time I do something like add or update a record?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "MunicipalityId,DirectorateName,UserEmailAddress, UserPassword")] RegisterDirectorateViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserEmailAddress, Email = model.UserEmailAddress };
            var createUserResult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.UserPassword);
                
            if (createUserResult.Succeeded)
            {
                // Add the user to the directorate role.
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, nameof(SystemRoles.Directorate));

                // Generate the directorate and add the user to it.
                var municipality = await db.Municipalities.FindAsync(model.MunicipalityId);
                var directorate = new Directorate
                {
                    Action = MetaAction.Create,
                    ActionBy = user,
                    ActionDate = DateTime.Now,
                    Municipality = municipality,
                    Name = model.DirectorateName
                };
                db.Directorates.Add(directorate);

                var directorateUser = new DirectorateUser
                {
                    Directorate = directorate,
                    User = user
                };
                db.DirectorateUsers.Add(directorateUser);

                // Expire the token so that it can't be used again.
                municipality.TokenExpiryDate = DateTime.Now;
                db.Entry(municipality).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();

                // Sign in the user and redirect to the dashboard.
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TempData["err"] = ex;
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
}
```

## EDIT

Here's extra models per comments...

```
public class Directorate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Municipality Municipality { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ActionBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActionDate { get; set; }
    public MetaAction Action { get; set; }
}
public class DirectorateUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Directorate Directorate { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
public class SubdirectorateUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Subdirectorate Subdirectorate { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Using a single SaveChanges or SaveChangesAsync works, and saves all batched changes. There's no question about that. Does your code throw perhaps? There's no logging in the catch block so any possible exceptions may be lost.

Comment: Post a *minimal* example that demonstrates the problem - just a console application, the necessary classes and code that creates a new DbContext, adds some entities then calls `SaveChanges`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no errors at all; the execution goes through to the Dashboard redirect and never gets into the catch block. Without posting 9000 lines of code, how do I post such an example to demonstrate?

Comment: What I described is about 10 lines and another 15 lines if the `Directorate` and `DirectoryUser` entities have only the fields shown here

Comment: Added the models... though there's something to be said for keeping proprietary information... well... proprietary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846329/usermanagers-autosavechanges-in-net-core-2-1

Answer (score 0):

You need many to many relationship. Though you have one User table and Directorates table so DirectorateUsers table contains Many-To-Many relationship between User/ApplicationUser  and Directorates. So you have to Customize the Model for Many to Many Relationship.

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public ApplicationUser() 
    {
        this.Directorates = new HashSet<Directorate>();
    }
....
    public virtual ICollection<Directorate> Directorates { get; set; }
}
```

And the Directorate Model has

```
public class Directorate
{
    public Directorate()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users{ get; set; }
}
```

Now the DbContext class looks like...

```
public class AppDBContext : DBContext
{
    public AppDBContext() : base("DefaultConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users{ get; set; }
    //or public DbSet<User> Users{ get; set; } //if ApplicationUser doesn't work
    public DbSet<Directorate> Directorates{ get; set; }
        
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        //Configure a Many-to-Many Relationship using Fluent API
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>() //or ApplicationUser
            .HasMany<Directorate>(s => s.Directorates)
            .WithMany(c => c.Users)
            .Map(cs =>
                    {
                        cs.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                        cs.MapRightKey("DirectorateId");
                        cs.ToTable("DirectorateUser");
                    });
    }
}
```

This mapping create a good relationship. please check the below link for many to many relationship.
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Now check your code db.SaveChangesAsync(); or without await simply db.SaveChanges()..
Hope this can work.Remember you have to mapping your Object in correct way.

Answer (score 0):

I see that when you are creating the Directorate and the DirectorateUser you are using the "user" variable, which may not be referring the one in the database.

Using the following variable instead of "user" to create the Directorate and the DirectorateUser may solve the issue.

```
var userDb = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName)
```

Comment: No change in behavior. Interestingly, SQL Profiler doesn't catch ANY queries to the database on the POST action

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue points to something at this.

```
            db.Entry(municipality).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This will only initiate saving changes related to municipality.

but, I think you should have something like this.

```
//set all objects that need to be updated in a modified state
                db.Entry(municipality).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.Entry(directorate).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.Entry(directorateUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
//finally save all the changes to the database.
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This is how, I would do it.

Comment: SaveChangesAsync isn't actually pushing any commands to SQL Server. Saw that last night when I realized I could check on SQL Profiler what's going on.

Comment: Then, I am not sure what to say. This code is picked from a project of mine that is live on server as I type this and it works good. looks like your issue is outside my pay grade :P

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using `UserManager` to access an `IdentityDbContext`. The Identity framework uses an instance of `IUserStore` to glue the two together. But as you've noticed, every operation immediately saves changes.

The default implementation, [`UserStore`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/UserStore.cs) already has a boolean property `AutoSaveChanges` to  prevent saving on every operation, however there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to access this property.

You could either replace the `IUserStore` service with your own implementation (as per [UserManager's AutoSaveChanges in .NET Core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846329/usermanagers-autosavechanges-in-net-core-2-1));

```cs
public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<IdentityUser>
{
    public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        AutoSaveChanges = false;
    }
}
services.AddScoped<IUserStore<IdentityUser>, CustomUserStore>();
```

Though you would then need to ensure that all UserManager / SigninManager calls are followed by another explicit save.

Or you could add `IUserStore` as a dependency, assume that it is an instance of `UserStore` and change the AutoSaveChanges value around your method;

```cs
private UserStore<IdentityUser, IdentityRole, DbContext> store;
public Controller(IUserStore<IdentityUser> store)
{
    this.store = store as UserStore<IdentityUser, IdentityRole, DbContext>;
}
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(...){
    try{
        store.AutoSaveChanges = false;
        ...
    }finally{
        store.AutoSaveChanges = true;
    }
}
```

Note that which UserStore generic type you need, depends on which IdentityContext generic type you are using.

Comment: A related, but rejected issue; https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7648.